# Regular expression for C# that matches all strings that has one or more word characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

### Solved

(see comments)

---

The title says everything...

I thought I can write RE (have done really complicated ones in Java or on the paper). Now I cannot write this simple one that I need to validate user names in ASP.NET MVC model attribute.  I would say that `"\\.*\\w\\.*"` should work according to resources that I've found. But it does not...

---

**EDIT:**

Here is what I have in my model code:

[image]

---

Here is the walidation taking place: [image]

As you can see string `a12` does not match but it should...

Comment: Anyway if you know about some real syntax reference for that crazy C# RE please leave me a comment.

Comment: Using `@` prefixed string literals for RE is a good idea. That way you need to only escape `"` and not every `\\` in the RE. Makes it *much* easier to read.

Comment: Why are you escaping the `.`? Doesn't that mean that your string must start/end with a sequence `.`? Don't you want the wildcard `.`?

Comment: Unless you say what exactly is that “it does not work”, it’s difficult to help. Anyway: Are you sure you want to match _dots_? You escape the dot so that it is literal, not “any character wildcard”.

Comment: IT DOES NOT WORK. Neither `"\\.*\\w\\.*"` nor `.*\\w.*` does what is in the title.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen in the title of this question is "matches all strings that has one or more word characters". It does not work means that it does not match some `string` containing one or more word characters. See my edit to for the pictures. By word characters I mean here any letter (maybe not from English alphabeth).

Comment: Ok I'm sorry - it is probably my Firefox again - it keeps buffering and showing me old versions of my page... So it is working now even if not as expected. I'll create another more specific quesion about what I need.

Comment: As writte below, try to change the datatype to "object" for your UserName property!

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please explain what it should match, instead of what it shouldn't. Describe how the username should look in terms of content chars.

Comment: @drasto I'm sorry, but "does not work" could mean many things. Like an exception, too many results, too few or no results. Please be more accurate next time.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen I apologize I will try.

Comment: @Tengiz as I've writen few comments above it should match any string that has at least one letter in it (that contains at least one letter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Word" in the context of regular expressions means non-whitespace, so `new Regex(@"\w")` is what you want in that case as e.g. `new Regex(@"\w").IsMatch(" 1 ")` returns true.

In a comment you say that you want letters to be matched, which wants `new Regex(@"[\p{L}]")` as `new Regex(@"[\p{L}]").IsMatch(" a ")` returns true but `new Regex(@"[\p{L}]").IsMatch(" 1 ")` returns false.

You can be more specific, treating this as `new Regex(@"[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}]")` which looks for lowercase, uppercase, titlecase, modifier and other letters specifically, in case one of those categories isn't wished for. E.g. to not consider modifier letters to be "word characters" you would use new `Regex(@"[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}]")`

If the regex has to match the entire expression then one like `.*\p{L}.*` would do the trick.

If you need it to *only* match word characters (banning all other characters) then you want `new Regex(@"^[\p{L}]+$")` which means: start of expression, one or more letters, end of expression.

Comment: I have also tried `.*\p{L}.*` but it did not work. The reason is that even if I'm specifying this regular expression in C# code, it gets transformed to JavaScript expression because it is specified as regular expression for client side validation (ASP.NET MVC). Java scrip regular expression does not allow unicode character classes like `L`. So the answer is: **it does not work and it will not work as I want it to. It cannot be done.** I like your answer it is the right one for C# regex even if does not work for this specific case (client side validation). I might accept it after some time...

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
(\w)+
```

It will returns all words

Comment: No. It may match strings containing numbers, space characters, anything. Only there must be one word character. Maybe I was missing bracers...

Comment: @drasto, it won't match space but it will match numbers because numbers *are* word characters, I think you mean you want just letters so I've given an answer to that, but this is correct for the question you asked.

Answer (score 0):

try your RegEx like the following:

```
String data = "drasto";

Regex regex  = new Regex(".*\\w.*");

var coll = regex.Matches(data);

foreach(var match in coll)
{
    Debug.Writeline(match.ToString());
}
```

This should work for your purpose.

Comment: This is the original version that I started with... It is not working as supposed... I'll try it again.

Comment: @drasto Your code has some `\ ` which cordellcp's doesn't have. And I think those `\ ` are incorrect.

Comment: @cordellcp3 I've just pasted code that you have provided here to my validator and it does not work - it matches inly strings that have exactly one character and that character is either letter or number (not a space for example). Try it yourself!

Comment: @drasto, I tried it with LinqPad and works just fine for me. http://www7.pic-upload.de/18.03.11/zv1chdb632li.png

Comment: @cordellcp3 well I'm missing something than. Maybe that `@` prefix will do the trick

Comment: Please see my edit of original question - added some pictures to show you that it seems to not work for me...

Comment: Hmm, try to change the datatype to "object" for your UserName property!